# trouble in search in java 2d arraylist?

Tags: java

I  want to create a login page using a 2d array list to store user name and password in java using eclipse. Insertion is successful but trouble in searching username from list as it found only last element. Full code is below

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> usercredentials = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> adduser = new ArrayList<String>();
@FXML
private TextField username_txt;
@FXML
private Label exixtancecheck_lbl;
@FXML
private TextField password_txt;
@FXML
private Label test;


public void register(ActionEvent Event) throws Exception
{
    register = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/register.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,500);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
    register.setScene(scene);
    register.show();
}
@FXML
private TextField  usernameregister_txt;
@FXML
private TextField  passwordregister_pswd;
@FXML
private TextField  confirmpasswordregister_pswd;
@FXML
private TextArea register_txtarea;
private Stage register;
// testing search by printing value on lable test

public void login(ActionEvent Event)

{

        for (int i = 0; i < usercredentials.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < usercredentials.get(i).size(); j++)
        {

            if(usercredentials.get(i).get(j).equals(usernameregister_txt.getText()))
           {

              test.setText("Found");
           }
          else 
          {
              test.setText("Not Found");  
          }


        }

    }
}

// above code only found last element

public void createuser(ActionEvent Event)
{
    if(passwordregister_pswd.getText().equals(confirmpasswordregister_pswd.getText()))
    {
        String username = usernameregister_txt.getText();
        String password = passwordregister_pswd.getText();


        adduser.add(username);
        adduser.add(password);
        usercredentials.add(adduser);
        usernameregister_txt.clear();
        passwordregister_pswd.clear();
        confirmpasswordregister_pswd.clear();


    }

    else
    {
        register_txtarea.setText("Password Not Match");
    }

    }
public void userdata(ActionEvent Event) 
{

    for(ArrayList<String> element:usercredentials)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<element.size();i++)
        {
            register_txtarea.appendText(element.get(i)+"\t");

        }register_txtarea.appendText("\n");
    }
}
```

output from userdata is 
admin   admin123    java    java123 
admin   admin123    java    java123

where admin and java is username while admin123 and java123 is password. Entered only once but show twice. if i enter 3 values it shows this 3 times

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the problem is in the ***for-loop*** of the ***login*** function.

The ***for-loop*** is supposed to `stop` when the element is found, but is always going till the last element, regardless of whether a match is found or not.

**The problem can be fixed as shown in the code snippet below, by adding a return statement that stops the loop when match is found.**

It can also be fixed by boolean flag or break statement.

```
public void login(ActionEvent Event) {

    // Initialise test to "Not found". 
    // test will be set to 'Found' only when a match is found.
    test.setText("Not Found");

    for (int i = 0; i < usercredentials.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < usercredentials.get(i).size(); j++) {
                if (usercredentials.get(i)
                        .get(j)
                        .equals(usernameregister_txt.getText())) {

                    // Match found. 
                    // Set test to 'Found' and exit the loop
                    test.setText("Found");
                    return;
               }
        }

    }
}
```